# Offline installation of xamarin in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

This link describes [Visual Studio 2015 setup Third-party dependencies](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3060693). but some components like `Xamarin` and `Visual C++ Mobile Development` are listed as third-party dependencies.

[image]

I need to install visual studio community with xamarin and visual c++ mobile development on a computer without the internet connection.

Does visual studio download these components for offline installation if I run `vs_community.exe` with `/layout` switch?

Answer (score 2):

An ISO Installer is prebuild version of VS2015 size of about 5.89 GB (with Update 1) and contains all downloaded stuffs that a standard VS users should have if you select typical and VS installs it for you upon downloading. If you want additional tools, you have to download them from the Internet.

The online installer is small setup and you have to download all the packages and development tools from the Internet. If you want to download all the packages and don't want to install (just download) then you have to use /layout at the root in CMD. You can also get the full ISO from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) by

Select Visual Studio 2015 -> Visual Studio Community Edition RC 2015 and choose ISO as download format.

Comment: Is it possible to have a fully offline installer with online installer `/layout` method ?  I want to install VS on other computers without the internet connection. I had downloaded VS community `ISO` but for installation it needs to get some components from the internet.

Comment: Yes, you can install. First download on one instance with all the development tools that you need and once downloaded, you can easily port it. I think it will take some time.

Comment: Yes, it takes sometimes. I think the final size of the installer is more than `15GB`. thank you for your reply

Comment: Make sure to mark as answer if you get your problem solved!